# Letting Google bot skip specified script

Tags: javascript

I've got a function (Java) that checks if a specified "I accept the terms" cookie has been set, if not it redirects the user to the "terms" page.

Now this easy to bypass, but that's not the point.

I got concern with Google bot and other crawlers.. 
I've read that redirecting Google bot would cause an 301 on the page, and then all my pages, would be 301 to the terms page...
Not God.

So I'm wondering how to tell my script that if it's Google bot (and other bot), to exit the script and ignore the redirect?

This is how it looks now:

```
    <!-- see if the i agree cookie is set, else send them to the info page -->

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";

    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);

    }

  window.location="https://my.site.se/startpage.html";
    return null;

}
```

And it's called by:

```
  <script>
readCookie('acceptterms');
</script>
```

It's a pretty simple script, but it still took me a few hours to get to work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually not a great idea to leave redirects to the client. It is also perhaps not a great idea detect a web crawler from your client.

If your use case cannot be helped, it is at a large extent possible to determine if your visitor is a crawler through javascript.

`navigator.userAgent` gives you a *userAgent string*, a sort of signature from the browser that is accessing your page. In the case of crawlers, this signature might contain words like "bot", "google", "baidu" etc.

Start by defining a general purpose Regex to match these crawler user agent strings:

```
var crawlerAgentRegex = /bot|google|aolbuild|baidu|bing|msn|duckduckgo|teoma|slurp|yandex/i;
```

Next wrap your redirection statement with an `if` check:

```
if (crawlerAgentRegex.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    console.log('not gonna redirect these guys');
} else {
    window.location="https://my.site.se/startpage.html";
}
```

On a side note, you do not need to `return null` at the end of the function body in your case.

Comment: Is there any other way to redirect users based on a cookie?

Comment: In your code, you wrote 'crawlerAgentRegex.test",  the  .test what's that?

Comment: 1. The other way would be to redirect users server-side, without even going into javascript and cookie-checking 2. The `test` checks if the regular expression matches the user agent string, it returns true or false accordingly.